# Can't seem to make these two classes run at once. Using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been trying to make one class, which has a rocket moving execute while another completely different class executes a fuel bar which decreases. Even with threading, my program makes the fuel bar get to 0, then the rocket executes.
Here is the code to my rocket:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Rocket extends JFrame
{
    ImageIcon Alien, BackGnd, Blast, Count1, Count2, Count3, Count4, Count5, Laser;
    ImageIcon RocketFall, RocketRight, RocketUp, RocketStill, RocketLand, Explosion, RocketBroke;
    Thread healthBar, Rocketeer;
    int i = 150;
    DebugMonitor dM = new DebugMonitor ();



    public Rocket ()
    {
        super ("The Rocket Program");

        setSize (900, 526);
        Toolkit dir = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();

        Alien = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("Alien.png"));
        BackGnd = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("Background.png"));
        Blast = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("Blastoff.png"));
        Count1 = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("CountDown1.png"));
        Count2 = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("CountDown2.png"));
        Count3 = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("CountDown3.png"));
        Count4 = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("CountDown4.png"));
        Count5 = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("CountDown5.png"));
        Laser = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("Laser.png"));
        RocketFall = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("RocketFall.png"));
        RocketRight = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("RocketTurned.png"));
        RocketUp = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("RocketMove.png"));
        RocketStill = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("RocketStill.png"));
        RocketLand = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("RocketLand.png"));
        Explosion = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("Explosion.png"));
        RocketBroke = new ImageIcon (dir.getImage ("RocketBroken.png"));

        healthBar = new Thread (dM);
        healthBar.start ();

        setVisible (true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        count (g);
        fast (g);
        // endProgram ();
    }


    public void endProgram ()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep (5000);
            //dM.endProgram = true;
            System.exit (0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }


    public void count (Graphics g)
    {
        try
        {

            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            RocketStill.paintIcon (this, g, 5, 440);
            Count5.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 400);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            RocketStill.paintIcon (this, g, 5, 440);
            Count4.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 400);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            RocketStill.paintIcon (this, g, 5, 440);
            Count3.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 400);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            RocketStill.paintIcon (this, g, 5, 440);
            Count2.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 400);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            RocketStill.paintIcon (this, g, 5, 440);
            Count1.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 400);
            Thread.sleep (1000);
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            RocketStill.paintIcon (this, g, 5, 440);
            Blast.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 400);
            Thread.sleep (600);
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {

        }
    }


    public void slow (Graphics g)
    {


        for (int i = 440 ; i > 30 ; i -= 5)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketUp.paintIcon (this, g, 5, i);
                Thread.sleep (50);

            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }

            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);

        }

        for (int i = 5, x = 340 ; i < 800 ; i += 5, x -= 5)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketRight.paintIcon (this, g, i, 35);
                Thread.sleep (50);
                System.out.println (i + "      " + x);

            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            Alien.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 460);
            Laser.paintIcon (this, g, 420, x - 30);
        }
        for (int i = 35 ; i < 400 ; i += 5)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketLand.paintIcon (this, g, 830, i);
                Thread.sleep (50);
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            Alien.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 460);

        }

    } //Method


    public void medium (Graphics g)
    {


        for (int i = 440 ; i > 30 ; i -= 10)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketUp.paintIcon (this, g, 5, i);
                Thread.sleep (50);

            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }

            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);

        }

        for (int i = 5, x = 340, z = 0 ; z == 0 ; i += 10, x -= 10)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketRight.paintIcon (this, g, i, 35);
                Thread.sleep (50);
                System.out.println (i + "      " + x);

            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            Alien.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 460);
            Laser.paintIcon (this, g, 420, x + 50);
            if (x == 30)
            {
                z = 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 35, x = -50 ; i < 400 ; i += 10, x += 3)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketFall.paintIcon (this, g, 440 + x, i);
                Thread.sleep (50);
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            Alien.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 460);
        }
        RocketBroke.paintIcon (this, g, 500, 450);

    } //Method


    public void fast (Graphics g)
    {


        for (int i = 440 ; i > 30 ; i -= 15)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketUp.paintIcon (this, g, 5, i);
                Thread.sleep (50);

            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }

            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);

        }

        for (int i = 5, x = 340, z = 0 ; z == 0 ; i += 10, x -= 15)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketRight.paintIcon (this, g, i, 35);
                Thread.sleep (50);


            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            Alien.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 460);
            Laser.paintIcon (this, g, 420, x + 50);
            if (x < 30)
            {
                z = 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 35, x = -50 ; i < 400 ; i += 10, x += 8)
        {
            try
            {
                RocketFall.paintIcon (this, g, 300 + x, i);
                Thread.sleep (50);
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
            }
            BackGnd.paintIcon (this, g, 0, 0);
            Alien.paintIcon (this, g, 400, 460);
        }
        RocketBroke.paintIcon (this, g, 500, 450);

    } //Method



    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new Rocket ();


        // Place your code here
    } // main method
} // Rocket class
```

Here is the code to my fuel bar:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class DebugMonitor extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    int i = 150;
    boolean endProgram = false;

    public DebugMonitor ()
    {
        super ("Debug Monitor");
        setLocation (1000, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize (151, 31);
        setVisible (true);
    }


    public void run (Graphics g)
    {
        for (; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (40);
                g.setColor (Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect (0, 0, 150, 30);
                g.setColor (Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillRect (0, 0, i, 30);
                Thread.sleep (20);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }




    // public static void main (String[] args)
    // {
    ///     new DebugMonitor ();
    //} // main method
} // DebugMonitor class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think two threads are not a good solution. Threads should execute tasks as **unrelated** as possible, because the timing is not defined. Here the tasks are very closely related. It would be easier to use one thread to update both the fuel and rocket at the same time.